# Understanding docker run -v command

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I was just going through **[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pe6a8Jbvi9E&list=PLfpPfDziPdMIbc7p-_siXYwqsRnd3jrLM&index=3)** on Youtube, trying to understand the use of the `-v` option at the `run` command.

Why is the author using the `-v` option? He uses the command, like so:

```
docker run -v /var/lib/mysql --name=my_datastore -d busybox echo "my datastore"
```

Now I understand the above command to an extent:

- `--name=my_datastore` gives the container a specific name.
- `-d busybox` starts a container in detached mode, based on the `busybox` image.

After the command is executed the below line is echoed to the console.

```
my datastore
```

Now, the part I don't understand is the following:

```
-v /var/lib/mysql
```

Why is the `-v` option used here, and why the path `/var/lib/mysql` specified?

I am having difficulty understanding why the above line is used and in what context. Can anybody explain?

Comment: if you do `docker run --help` you will get, among other things , `-v, --volume=[]                 Bind mount a volume
`

Comment: @user2915097 i don't understand the context of its usage , and so i aksed the question , can you explain ... step by step to me , what is happening , its hard for me to put the blocks togeather !

Comment: usually, we put the source and destination, like `-v $HOME/.rainbow_oauth:/root/.rainbow_oaut`  (this is an example from https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The `-v` (or `--volume`) argument to `docker run` is for creating storage space inside a container that is separate from the rest of the container filesystem.  There are two forms of the command.

When given a single argument, like `-v /var/lib/mysql`, this allocates space from Docker and mounts it at the given location. This is primarily a way of allocating storage from Docker that is *distinct* from your service container.  For example, you may want to run a newer version of a database application, which involves tearing down your existing MySQL container and starting a new one.  You want your *data* to survive this process, so you store it in a volume that can be accessed by your database container.

When given two arguments (`host_path:container_path`), like `-v /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`, this mounts the specified directory on the host inside the container at the specified path (and, to be accurate, this can also be used to expose host *files* inside the container; for example `-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime` would make `/etc/localtime` on the host available as `/etc/localtime` inside the container).  This is a way of either feeding information into your container, or providing a way for your container to make files accessible to the host.

If a container has volumes available, either through the use of the `-v` command line argument or via the `VOLUME` directive in a Dockerfile, these volumes can be accessed from another container using the `--volumes-from` option:

```
docker run --volumes-from my_datastore ...
```

This will make any volumes defined in the source container available in the container you're starting with `--volumes-from`.

This is discussed in more detail in the [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) documentation.

Comment: The last documentation link is dead now

Comment: this answer has become a bit outdated. `-v` has a slightly different syntax and the `--mount` option is recommended for new users instead.

Comment: what is the new syntax?

Comment: I've updated the link to point to the current docs. I don't think the syntax of `-v` has changed substantially (there are new modifiers you can tack onto the end, but the basic syntax is the same). If you follow the link there is a discussion of `-v` vs `--mount`.

Comment: What is `:ro` in `-v /etc:/node/etc:ro`? @larsks

Comment: That creates a read-only volume mount, so the container can't modify the files in that directory.