# Running a Dockerized Python application with I/O

Tags: python, docker

I have a Dockerized Python script which is normally run locally as:

```
python script.py -f path/to/video/file
```

This code will produce a text file and a directory with images in the directory from which it was run.

So suppose I have this Python script on a Docker container and I use:

```
docker run container python script.py -f path/to/video/file
```

Is it possible to specify a local video file and have the output saved locally too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have to utilize the `-v` option. Coping from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32270232/2194843):

> When given two arguments (host_path:container_path), like -v /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql,
> this mounts the specified directory on the host inside the container
> at the specified path (and, to be accurate, this can also be used to
> expose host files inside the container; for example -v
> /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime would make /etc/localtime on the host
> available as /etc/localtime inside the container). This is a way of
> either feeding information into your container, or providing a way for
> your container to make files accessible to the host.